# How to set up the api-platform react-admin graphql stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-admin, api-platform.com

I'm setting up an **Api-platform** (graphql enabled) server and a  **react-admin** client.
I create a resource on api-platform (name Domain). If i query GraphQL Playground app i get expected results.
After react-admin installed with the ra-data-graphql-simple package, the client try to connect and the client return an error "Unknown resource domains. Make sure it has been declared on your server side schema"

Here is my App.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, Delete } from 'react-admin';
import buildGraphQLProvider from 'ra-data-graphql-simple';
import myBuildQuery from './dataProvider';
import { DomainShow, DomainEdit, DomainCreate, DomainList } from './domain';
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { dataProvider: null };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
        const introspectionOptions = {
            include: ['Domains', 'Purchases'],
        };

      buildGraphQLProvider({ 
            //buildQuery: myBuildQuery, 
            clientOptions: { uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/graphql' },
            introspection: introspectionOptions

        })
        .then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }));
  }

  render() {
      const { dataProvider } = this.state;

      if (!dataProvider) {
          return <div>Loading</div>;
      }

      return (
          <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
              <Resource name="domains" list={ DomainList } create={ DomainCreate } show={ DomainShow } edit={ DomainEdit } title="Domains"/>
          </Admin>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```